# Must a function's definition be inclusive of all domain elements?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was reading V.K. Balakrishnan's book Introductory Discrete Mathematics, and came across this example on page 7:

[Link to example 0.2.2 in Balakrishnan 2011](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwZOZ.png)

Is this a typo? Must the domain set A include the element d for this example to make sense, or is there some concept I'm missing where A = {a, b, c} without d will suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely a typo. The definition was probably meant to be $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$.